# Get the mean between two dates

Tags: r, date

I would like to calculate the mean of a variable between two dates.

Here the example of data frames

```
library(lubridate) #ymd function

day= rep(seq.Date(from=ymd("2020-03-01"),to=ymd("2020-04-15"),by="day"), times=4)
center= rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each=46)
ocupation= as.numeric(round(runif(184,20,40),1))
df <- data.frame(day,center,ocupation)


start <- mdy("03/15/2020","04/12/2020","05/01/2020","02/13/2020")
end <- mdy("03/20/2020","04/28/2020","05/14/2020","03/01/2020")
center<-c("A", "A", "B", "C")
id<-c(1,2,3,4)
patients <- data.frame(id, center,start,end)
```

The shown data frame of patients it is just a sample, the original contains more than 12.000 ids

From each id, I would like to get the mean occupation between the start and the end dates in the center

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function that returns the average occupancy for one id:

```
mean.occ = function(id, patients, occupency, day, center){
  to.select = day > patients[id, "start"] & day < patients[id, "end"] & center == patients[id, "center"]
  return(mean(occupency[to.select]))
}
```

here, `day > patients[id, "start"] & day < patients[id, "end"] & center == patients[id, "center"]` select the ocuupency values between the start and end dates for a specific id and corresponding to the given center.

Then use `sapply` to apply it to each ids:

```
mean.occupancies = sapply(patients$id, FUN = mean.occ, patients, ocupation, day, center)
```

It is finally possible to add the results to the `patients` data frame:

```
patients = cbind.data.frame(patients, mean.occupancies)
```

Comment: The problem of this approach it is it doesn't take into account that each center has an specific occupancy

Comment: Indeed, I missed that point. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: It gives me an error,   Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.table", ">.Date") for ">"

Comment: it fine for me (I had to replace rbind.data.frame by cbind.data.frame though...). Maybe because the package data.table is loaded and overwrite some functions? If it's the case, restarting R should solve the issue (as soon as data.table is not loaded)

Comment: ahhh.... and ocupation was written occupation in the sapply...

Comment: Despite I added a na.rm=T into the mean.occ function, I obtain many NaN for  most of the id. Also in warnings it says In day > patients[id, "start"] & day < patients[id, "end"] &  ... :longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Do you have that problem in the example you gave? With his example I have NaN for the ids 3 (starting date is later than any date is in the vector day) and 4 (end date is earlier thanthe dates in vector day)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `dplyr` package from `tidyverse`.

```
df <- as_tibble(df)

library(dplyr) # 1.0.0

df %>%
        # find only the days in df corresponding to day ranges in patients
        filter(day %in% c(seq(patients[1, 3], patients[1, 4], by = "days"),
                         seq(patients[2, 3], patients[2, 4], by = "days"),
                         seq(patients[3, 3], patients[3, 4], by = "days"),
                         seq(patients[4, 3], patients[4, 4], by = "days"))) %>%
        # add id column
        mutate(id = ifelse(day %in% seq(patients[1, 3], patients[1, 4], by = "days"), patients$id[1],
                           ifelse(day %in% seq(patients[2, 3], patients[2, 4], by = "days"), patients$id[2],
                                  ifelse(day %in% seq(patients[3, 3], patients[3, 4], by = "days"), patients$id[3], patients$id[4])))) %>%
        # group by id
        group_by(id) %>%
        # find mean occuption for each id
        summarise(mean_occupation = mean(ocupation))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id mean_occupation
  <dbl>           <dbl>
1     1            29.7
2     2            31.7
3     4            32.2
```

**EDIT**

Version with `for` loops for many `id`'s:

```
df <- as_tibble(df)
library(dplyr)

# create days vector from patients
days <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(patients)) {
        dates <- seq(patients[i, 3], patients[i, 4], by = "days")
        for (j in 1:length(dates)) {
                names(dates)[j] <- patients$id[i]
        }
        days[[i]] <- dates
}
days <- as.Date(unlist(days), origin = "1970-01-01")

# filter df for days
mid <- df %>%
        filter(day %in% days)

# create id col (I couldn't do this directly in mutate())
id <- character()
for (i in 1:nrow(mid)) {
        id[i] <- names(days)[which(days == mid$day[i])]
}

# bind together and finish
final <- mid %>%
        cbind(id) %>% as_tibble() %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        summarise(mean_occupation = mean(ocupation))
```

```
> final
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  id    mean_occupation
  <chr>           <dbl>
1 1                29.7
2 2                31.7
3 4                32.2
```

Comment: The problem of this approach it is that it is not just 4 ids, but 12000

Comment: No problem, I'll create a `for` loop so that the code isn't so repetitive

Comment: The problem now it is that for each day there can be multiple ids, not just one, and in your solution (at least how I tried, it just get one id per day)